# change first page of android wear notification

Tags: android, notifications, wear-os

I have a notification on the handheld with a big text style:

```
notif.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                .bigText(bigLine).setBigContentTitle(titleLine));
```

This causes the corresponding Wear notification to have this extended text on the first page. 
Is there any way to change what is shown on the first page for the wearable only, while leaving the handheld notification unchanged?

In the end, I'd like to split out the bigText value into pages for the wearable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to split the text from your notifications into few pages - it seems like you have few "items" in one notification and want show them separately on wearable device. If you really have such scenario you should consider using the [grouping functionality](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/stacks.html)

This feature is used for example in Gmail app. You basically have one group notification (but with [`InboxStyle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.InboxStyle.html) instead of [`BigTextStyle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle.html)) on your mobile and multiple notifications on wearable device within one group.

### Group notification

You need to set the same `groupKey` for all these notifications by using method [`setGroup (String groupKey)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setGroup(java.lang.String))
and then use method [`setGroupSummary (boolean isGroupSummary)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setGroupSummary(boolean)) with `true` value to ndicate which one is a **summary** notification and should be displayed only on mobile. A **non-summary** notifications will show up only on wearable device.

### Two grouping approaches

1. Using this approach you can submit one notification (group summary notification) on your phone and multiple notifications on the wearable that will be displayed as a one group. So you will end up with something like

   - **MOBILE:** 1 group summary notification
   - **WEAR:** X notifications within a group
2. But if you really want to have one notification with X pages instead of X notifications you can work it around in following configuration:

   - **MOBILE:** 1 group summary notification
   - **WEAR:** 1 notification "within a group" with X pages

Comment: Thanks so much! Option 2 worked exactly as I needed.